# Why does the inside of ear smell nice?

Tags: human-ear

You can judge my habits later, but sometimes I stick my finger in my ear and smell my finger. When doing this, I get a pleasant smell for some reason. I haven't use hair lotion for a long time cause I have like no hair. I suspect it has to do with my headphones since I wear them often, but i have them for more than a year.

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE. You could visit the [tour-page](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) for basic informations, the [help-page](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help) for more detailed informations about what [could be asked](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [could not be](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). For formatting tasks in command prompt, visit [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) help sub-page. Thanks.

Comment: Did anyone else stick their finger in their ear and smell it?